Order of Polarities/Dipole Moments of CH3F, CH3Cl, CH3Br and CH3I
While explaining how to decide polarities/dipole moments of molecules, my teacher highlighted an exception to the statement:

For similar compounds like hydrides formed by different elements of a group, magnitude of partial charge or equivalently electronegativity of the atom of the group being considered decides its polarity relative to other compounds. For example, the order of polarities of the following compounds is
$$\ce{H2O>H2S>H2Se>H2Te}$$

But in case of $\ce{CH3F, CH3Cl, CH3Br}$ and $\ce{CH3I}$, the order of
$\ce{CH3F}$ and $\ce{CH3Cl}$ reverses since internuclear distance is the prominent factor in deciding polarity:
$$\ce{CH3Cl>CH3F>CH3Br>CH3I}$$
My teacher further said that there is no genuine explanation for this result as of now. Is there any experimental basis and/or reasoning for this anomaly?

MathJax should not be used in titles unless absolutely necessary. Here — just as in the case of classical typography guidelines — either the spelled out chemical names or the blanket term like halomethanes would be a better alternative.
